# Strong convergence of rotation by 1/n operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

let $ A_n: L^2([-\pi,\pi]) \rightarrow L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ be $ A_nf(t)=f(t-\frac{1}{n}) $.

Does $(A_n)$ converge in the strong operator topology?

Comment: This is translation, not rotation ;)

Comment: I am thinking of it as a rotation because I actually meant that for example, $A_nf(-\pi + \frac{1}{2n}) = f(\pi -  \frac{1}{2n})$

Answer (score 1):

It does converge in the strong operator topology. You can approximate $f$ in $L^2$ by a $2\pi$-periodic, continuous function $g$, and the strong convergence is clear for such a $g$.